# Authentication for Google Cloud (Document AI)

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, cloud-document-ai

First off, please be kind, as I'm not a developer and may struggle with some basics concepts.

I'm trying to build an AI Invoice reader to collect invoice data in a spreadsheet, using Integromat / make.com (no-code platform) and Google Cloud Services.
Usually, there are integrations for what I need in Integromat or I use simple REST calls.

With the Document AI, afaik I have to use OAuth. I have my "processor" and the Client ID and Client secret for Integromat. What I'm now missing are:

- Authorize URI
- Token URI

I've been searching the [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/send-request) for a while, but for a non-dev it's quite confusing. Where can I find the two URLs needed?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It appears that you can use a Service Account ([Before you begin](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/before-you-begin)).

Answer (score 1):

For authentication, you can create a Service Account and key to connect to Google Cloud Services. You can read the [before you begin](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/before-you-begin) guide which covers how to create the service account, and assign permissions.

Not familiar with how Integromat works, but you can probably use a similar process to how [Google Cloud Storage](https://www.integromat.com/en/integrations/google-cloud-storage) integrations work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the missing resources for OAuth2 authorization:

```
"auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
"token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
"scope":  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
```

But with this, I have to re-authenticate every now ant then - I don't know why.

Source:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#httprest_1
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes

And, as Holt Skinner already mentioned, the Google Docs writes to use a Service Account. Unfortunately, I don't know how to use a Service Account in Integromat/make.com. (My challenge is to insert the JSON keyfile).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).